# Java program to parse the string and get the character count

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am supposed to write a program to parse the molecule and get the atoms count.
Like this:
C6H12OH and the output should be `C=6, O=1, H=13`

This is the code I've written so far:

```
class ParseMolecule 
{ 
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        System.out.println("The atoms count in the molecule C6H12OH is :" + getElementsMap("C6H12OH"));
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> getElementsMap(String molecule) 
    {
        for(char c : molecule.toCharArray())
        {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't my homework or anything. I just found this on a website and I was trying to figure it out.

Comment: you need to show more effort

Comment: That's how you learn - by figuring it out.  If we write the program for you, we rob you of the experience.

Comment: [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) will be your friend here.

Comment: A good start is to just figure out how you'd do it by hand, and start by implementing that. It may not give you the most elegant solution, but it will give you _a_ solution you can improve on as you learn.

Comment: public static Map<String, Integer> getElementsMap(String molecule) {
    
int num[] = new int[10];
char ch[] = new char[12];
    
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){

char c = molecule.toCharArray();
if(Character.isLetter(c)
{
    System.out.print(c + "=");
}
else
 System.out.print(c);


}

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the following (works only for elements represented by a single character) :

```
   String input = "C6H12OH";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z])([0-9]*)");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
   Map <Character, Integer> atoms = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
   while (m.find()) {
       Character element = m.group(1).charAt(0);
       Integer count =  Integer.parseInt(m.group(2).equals("") ? "1" : m.group(2));
       atoms.put(element, count + (atoms.get(element) == null ? 0 : atoms.get(element)));
   }
   System.out.println(atoms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
char last = 0
for (char c: input)
  if (!isDecimal(c))
    if (count == 0) // no number between 2 characters
      count = 1
    map[last] += count
    last = c
    count = 0
  else
    count = count*10 + charToInt(c)
    last = 0
```